Jenkins:Pipeline script failure to parse command
This is a Jenkins pipeline script running on a Windows Server 2016 node
   stage('clone') {
            steps {
                script {
                    dir("${WORKSPACE}") {
                        if (fileExists("foobar")) {
                            echo 'Updating workspace for Foobar application'
                            dir ("${WORKSPACE}/foobar") {
                                bat ("git fetch origin master")
                            }
                        }  else {
                            echo 'Building Workspace for Foobar Application'
                            def command="git clone -c http.extraHeader='Authorization: Bearer <HTTPACCESSToken>' https://myserver:port/scm/psrc/foobar.git"
                            bat ("${command}")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

The string in the 'command' variable is correctly constructed and echoed to the build log.  I can copy that echo into a PS terminal and the command executes perfectly.  It also works perfectly in a plain DOS terminal.
However in Jenkins pipeline, the string is NOT properly parsed into DOS and I get:
fatal: Too many arguments.

usage: git clone [<options>] [--] <repo> [<dir>]

    -v, --[no-]verbose    be more verbose
    -q, --[no-]quiet      be more quiet

I can solve that issue with escaped double quotes surrounding the parameter for -c but then the GIT command does not properly use the header and I get a username prompt.
I am completely stuck right now.  I have tried every possible manner of quoting and escaping of quotes and can not get this to work.

Never ever checkout the code manually - let Jenkins do it for you instead and set up the branch sources for your pipeline accordingly - you will get both security and flexibility provided by the existing (Git plugin, to be precise) tooling. As for the problem itself - this could be related, and this might help if you're really ready to dive in to understand the quoting issues in Jenkins.

Yea, well that isn't working either.  We are using HTTP access tokens and apparently the plugin does not know how to do that. '''[Pipeline] git
The recommended git tool is: NONE
Warning: CredentialId "" could not be found.'''  And the quoting thing is a real bug.  From what I can see you CAN NOT craft a git clone command with config commands in it and pass it to the jenkins WINDOWS command parser.  It works fine in linux.
